# How to add a <hr> in Symfony2 form builder?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am building a form using the formbuilder, where I need to add `<hr/>` after certain fields. How can I do that? FYI, Need to add `<hr/>` after the field `priority` and another before `biography`. My form builder:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text',
        array(
            'label' => 'Name English',

        ))
        ->add('bangla_name','text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Name Bangla',
                'required' => false
            ))
        ->add('real_name','text',
            array(
                'required' => false

            ))

        ->add('debut', 'text',array(
            'label' => 'Debut Film',
            'required' => false))
        ->add('birth_place','text',array(
            'label'=> 'Birth Place',
            'required' => false
        ))

        ->add('sex', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female', 'N/A' => 'N/A'),
            'row_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-6 n-p-l'),
            'label'=> 'Sex',

            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-md-4'
            ),
        ))
        ->add('priority','choice', array('required' => true, 'label'=> 'Priority','attr'=> array('class'=>'col-md-2'), 'choices' => array(
            '0' => '0',
            '1' => '1',
            '2' => '2',
            '3' => '3',
            '4' => '4'
        ), 'row_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'col-sm-4'
        ),
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-md-6'
            ),
         ))
        ->add('bday','choice',
            array(
                'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildDayChoices(),'label'=> 'Birth Day',
                'row_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                'help' => '*required',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-6'
                )
            ))
        ->add('bmonth','choice',
            array(
                'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildMonthChoices(),'label'=> 'Birth Month',
                'row_attr' => array(
    'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                'help' => '*required',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-6'
                ),
            ))
        ->add('byear','choice',
                array(
                    'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildYearChoices(),'label'=> 'Birth Year',
                    'row_attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                    'help' => '*required',
                    'label_attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-md-6'
                    ),
                ))
        ->add('dod_day','choice',
            array(
                'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildDayChoices(),'label'=> 'Death Day',
                'row_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                'help' => '*required',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-6'
                ),

            ))
        ->add('dod_month','choice',
            array(
                'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildDayChoices(),'label'=> 'Death Month',
                'row_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                'help' => '*required',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-6'
                ),
            ))
        ->add('dod_year','choice',
            array(
                'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildDayChoices(),'label'=> 'Death Year',
                'row_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-4 n-p-l'),
                'help' => '*required',
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-md-6'
                ),
            ))



       // ->add('birth','birthday', array('label' => 'Date of Birth', 'years' => range(1950, date('Y')-10)))

        ->add('bio_english','textarea',array(
           'label'=> 'Biography - English',
       ))
        ->add('bio_bangla','textarea',array(
            'label'=> 'Biography - Bangla',
        ))
        ->add('graphics', 'graphics', array(
            'upload_directory' => 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'artist','row_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-12')
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating custom template just for that field? Symfony provides a way to override any specific field of your form so you can render the field just as you like. If you are interested, I can write you an answer about it.

Comment: Please do and I'll see if it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, as I said in comments, one way would be to override specific field of your form. If you are interested in the subject, you can read more [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)

For the purpose of demonstrating, I've created simple form with 3 fields, as follows:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('username', 'text');
    $builder->add('email', 'email');
    $builder->add('password', 'password');
}
```

Now, the important part here is the name of the form (it's used later when overriding)

```
public function getName() {
    return 'myform';
}
```

Nothing new here, most of the magic happens in your template file.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

The following line tells Symfony that you are using the same template file as a base to create a form theme. Next:

```
{% block _myform_email_row %}
    {{ block('form_row') }}
    <hr/>
{% endblock %}
```

This block is all you need to define at the top of your template, after `{% form_theme ... %}`

`{% block _myform_email_row %}`

- `_myform` is the name of your form obviously.
- `_email` is the name of the input you want to override
- `_row` is what part of it you want to override. `row` stands for label, widget and block. `_widget` would override only the part that renders the input.

And that's all you need. Define custom block, render the default block and add `<hr/>` at the end of it. You can override any template part like that.

**Edit - response to a comment**

> but can't exactly use it because I can't use {% form_theme form _self %}

You can delete the whole `{% form_theme %}` line and move your custom `{% block _myform_... %}` to separate template. Then open your config.yml, look for the section `twig` and include the template as a resource, like this:

```
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
form:
    resources:
        - theme/custom.html.twig
```

> Here my template is located in app/Resources/views/theme

This will include your template in every form you have. But since you override specific field of specific form, it should not interact with other forms. This way would save you the trouble of using `{% form_theme %}` block.

Comment: I got the idea, but can't exactly use it because I can't use `{% form_theme form _self %}`. Thanks for the answer, I think I can use it to find a workaround.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti I've update my answer with another suggestion. Take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. A horizontal rule is not a form construct, and as such, has no business being defined by a FormBuilder.

This needs to be handled in the view/template

```
{{ form_row(form.priority) }}
<hr/>
{{ form_row(form.bday) }}
```

IMO, you've been a bit too liberal with your use of the HTML properties in your builder. Those should be used only if you really need them. Again, they are primarily view concerns.

### EDIT

You can add this customization in the form's view, and [override the `form_row` block](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row) to be aware of this customization

**src/AppBundle/Form/YourFormType.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /* ... Rest of form type ... */

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view['priority']->use_separator = true;
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);
    }
}
```

Then the form block

```
{% block form_row %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% if form.use_separator is defined %}
        <hr/>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I know, but I can't render the fields separately. Too many templates in too many places. I'll have to write the forms for the rest of my life! :'(

Comment: Twig has a lot of mechanisms for template/fragment re-use. I'd have to imagine that one of those can help you.

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer